# What's the reaction here?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, teaching-lab

I have found a gif photo on the internet and I am very curious what is happening there? What reaction is the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: I kinda like the GIF, but using dangerous, reactive reagents such as concentrated $\ce{H2O2}$ to perform a rather violent reaction ***without*** any safety glasses?  Bad idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\ce{KI}$ with $\ce{H2O2}$ with a tiny bit of dishwashing liquid. It is a rather violent redox reaction wherein $\ce{H2O2}$ is decomposed to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$. You can actually see that $\ce{I2}$ is being formed by the brownish-yellowish color in the beginning of the reaction.

There is a lot of information about this reaction. I performed this reaction quite a few times myself for my students. It is a lot of fun. Some people call it making elephant toothpaste. :-)